# Is there an analog to logit Y-aware PCA for correspondence analysis?

Tags: logistic, correspondence-analysis, multinomial-logit

I came across this [tutorial](https://github.com/WinVector/Examples/blob/master/PCR/YAwarePCAclassification.md) of logit Y-aware PCA for dichotomous $Y$s. Does anyone know if there is an analogous procedure for correspondence analysis?

It seems that there couldn't be since the Y-aware scaling would change the categorical variables to be continuous, and, hence correspondence analysis would not be apropriate for them. Could PCA then be used on these "y logistic link units" scaled variables instead?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267769/can-y-aware-pca-be-performed-with-binary-independent-variables